# Need Breadcrum structure without change in URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, navigation, custom-post-type, breadcrumbs

I have wordpress website and it's all url is 
**www.example.com/product-page.html** and also my Breadcrumb look like **Home > Product-page**  it is as regular.

but now when i set parent as product page then it breadcrumb is perfact, like Home > Product > Product-page

also url is changes to www.example.com/product/product-page.html.

instead of above I want this as it is like : www.example.com/product-page.html

(i want to change breadcrumb not url if i set parent.)

please suggest some solutions

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plug-in to define your produts URL without /product/ prefix : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

### Edit :

This plugin for wordpress, named "custom permalinks", permit you to define pages/posts URL without any prefix (in this case '/product/') event if you attach the page/post to a parent page/post